# Problems saved as 3gp files when screen recording on Android9

Tags: mediarecorder, mediastore, screen-capture, android-9.0-pie, 3gp

In Android 9, even if you specify MIME_TYPE of MediaStore as "video/mp4" and DISPLAY_NAME as "fileName.mp4", it will be saved as a 3gp file.

In Android 10, it works without problems.

How to solve this problem

```
       val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, fileName)
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, dateSeconds)
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED, dateSeconds)
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
            }
        }

        val itemUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)

        contentResolver.openOutputStream(itemUri, "w")?.use { os ->
            tempFile.inputStream().copyTo(os)
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            contentValues.clear()
            contentValues.apply {
                put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
            }
            contentResolver.update(itemUri, contentValues, null, null)
        }
```

Comment: have you been able to solve this problem? i am facing the same issue :/